# mPDF: Is there any way to insert a Cropbox or Bleedbox, or to change the values of the trimbox?

Tags: php, mpdf

I want to output print pdfs and need to establish a trimbox smaller than the media box or to setup crop box and bleed box. Is there any way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What package you are using for pdf generation? Better share code samples you tried already

Comment: @Sheik I'm using v8.1.2, here is the general code to set up the pdf:
   
    $pdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
        'mode' => 'utf-8',
        'format' => [226,313],
        'fontDir' => array_merge($fontDirs, [
            $assets.'vendor/mpdf/custom/fonts',
        ]),
        'fontdata' => $fontData + [
            'sanchezslab' => [
                'R' => 'a.ttf',
                'B' => 'b.ttf'
            ]
        ],
        'default_font' => 'sanchezslab'
    ]);
    $pdf->PDFX = true;

Comment: The paper format is 210x297mm.

Comment: Please add the above information to the question itself, instead of hiding it in a comment. That would also allow you to format your code to make it more readable.